# does std::function reset its internal function after being moved

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <functional>

        template <class F>
        class ScopeExitFunction
        {
        public:
            ScopeExitFunction(F& func) throw() :
                m_func(func)
            {
            }

            ScopeExitFunction(F&& func) throw() :
                m_func(std::move<F>(func))
            {
            }

            ScopeExitFunction(ScopeExitFunction&& other) throw() :
                m_func(std::move(other.m_func))
            {
             //  other.m_func = []{};
            }

            ~ScopeExitFunction() throw()
            {
                m_func();
            }

        private:
            F m_func;
        };

int main() {
    {
        std::function<void()> lambda = [] { cout << "called" << endl; };
        ScopeExitFunction<decltype(lambda)> f(lambda);
        ScopeExitFunction<decltype(lambda)> f2(std::move(f));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

without uncomment this line `//  other.m_func = []{};`
the program produce this output :

> Executing the program.... $demo  called terminate called after
>   throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call' what():
>   bad_function_call

is it normal that std::function doesn't reset his internal function when moved ?

Comment: `std::forward<F>(func)`, in the constructor from an `F&&` is just an awkward way of saying `std::move(func)`.

Comment: there is a bug under msvc2013 that's why I use std::forward

Comment: erratum bug with msvc2010

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to C++11 20.8.11.2.1/6 [func.wrap.func.con], move-constructing from an existing `std::function` object leaves the original object "in a valid state with an unspecified value". So basically don't assume anything. Just don't use the original function object, or don't move from it if you still need it.

Comment: or write your own `::std::function` lookalike.

Comment: @user1095108: *why*...?

Comment: Perhaps he expects something from `::std::function` that is not there.

Comment: You could of course check if the moved-from object still has a target, but you don't know if the bound members are in any sensible state, so there's really nothing you can do with the moved-from object. So don't move if you still want to use it. At best you might want to check if someone has *conditionally* taken ownership from an object you pass via lvalue reference; in that case, you can instruct the caller to reset the function to signal that ownership has been taken.

Comment: @KerrekSB "why...?" - to learn why there's no need to write one!

Comment: @DanielEarwicker you learn by doing, so there is always a need to write one!

Answer (score 5):

> is it normal that std::function doesn't reset his internal function when moved ?

On the contrary, in your case it *does* reset the internal function, meaning the internal handle is set to zero, and the `std::function` is not a real function any more. And since that happened the call to `operator()` does not go well.